# Change filename of attachments on Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I'm using `cfmailparam` to attach files to an email. I'm getting the filenames and paths from my database. Normally, the attached files have unique names, but I can get their original filenames by querying the following columns in a database table:

- `ASSET_FILE_NAME`: unique name
- `ASSET_REAL_NAME`: original_name_before_upload.pdf

When I send the e-mail with cfmail, the attachments still use the unique names, but I really need to rename them. I've searched and tried also:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#assetfiles.RecordCount#" index="i">
    <cfmailparam
        file="C:\files\#assetfiles.ASSET_FILE_NAME[i]#"
        type="application/pdf"
        disposition="attachment; filename=""#assetfiles.ASSET_REAL_NAME[i]#"""
    />
</cfloop>
```

But this is not working for all attachment files. It changes just 1 filename and the other ones still use the unique names.

Is there anyway to make this possible?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways you could do this

1. You could rename the files themselves
2. Create duplicates and then use the `remove="true"` attribute of [`cfmailparam`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmailparam.html)
3. Read the files with the odd names and attach them with a new name `<cfmailparam file="niceName.pdf" content="#fileRead(oddName.pdf)#">`

Comment: Dear Matt Busche, thanks for your reply. I'm trying it now. I'll be write again result if success or not. Thanks again.

Comment: Option 2 worked for me. However, in my case option 3 created a correctly name attached but empty pdf file. Using CF9,0,1,274733.