# Attaching and naming a file in cfmail

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I have a simple cfmail with an attachment. The file on the server has one name, but I'd like to call it something else when attached to the email. I tried:

```
<CFMAILPARAM FILE="#OriginalFile#" DISPOSITION="attachment; filename=""#AttachFile#""">
```

That works in certain email clients:

- Thunderbird - All good
- Outlook - No
- Yahoo (on desktop) - No
- Yahoo (on android) - Yes
- GMail - Yes

Is there anyway, regardless of email client, I can get it to use the filename I want?!

Comment: You  could always make a copy with the name you want.

Comment: @DanBracuk i guess i could do, and may have to, but i'd like to avoid if possible. this cfmail is part of a larger process that is generating a few hundred pdf files, naming them from their unique database reference id ( to avoid any possible duplicate filenames ) and them emailing them out.

Comment: (Edit) Out of curiosity, what file name do the other clients use instead? Related [Change filename of attachments on Coldfusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865183/change-filename-of-attachments-on-coldfusion). I realize you want to avoid renaming, but typically the file name is a "suggestion" to the client. I am not sure it is possible to enforce it.

Comment: See [RFC 2183](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2183) *"..The sender may want to suggest a filename ... It is important that the receiving MUA not blindly use the suggested
filename.*"

Comment: @Leigh the filename used is #OriginalFile# where #AttachFile# is ignored. i guess that rfc makes sense, you wouldn't want people to able to be send you an executable for example, but pretend its something else. thanks.

Comment: @luke - Exactly.  I suspect that is why they noted it as a suggestion for mail clients, not a mandate. Only other thing I can think of would be to try reading in the file into a variable, and using the `content` variable instead of `file`.  If that does not work, you may be out of luck and will have to use a temp file and delete it (as mentioned on the link above).

Comment: I nominate @Leigh to post her comment about RFC 2813 as an answer.

Comment: First I would be curious to know what effect (if any) using `content` instead of `file` had with the problem mail clients above. Also, what was the result of using a physical `file` (with the desired name) with those same clients.

Comment: if anyone reads this looking for a solution,  i was just reading that in cf2016 theres a new cfmailparam attribute called filename 'The file name of the attachment as seen by the recipient.' unfortunately i'm not on 2016 yet